# Stack (rbind) two different table or tibble together

Tags: r

I want to stack two different table or tibble in R. But if I use rbind() or bind_rows(), I have a table but that is not what I want. Both don't have any common ID or variables. For example,

```
 xx <- mtcars %>%
   group_by(vs) %>%
   summarize(mean(mpg), sd(mpg)) 

 yy <- mtcars %>%
   group_by(am) %>%
   summarise(mean(wt), sd(wt))
```

I want to have this outcome:

```
am  mean(wt)   sd(wt)
 0       3.77    0.777
 1       2.41    0.617
vs  mean(mpg)  sd(mpg)
 0       16.6    3.86
 1       24.6    5.38
```

I have tried multiple different ways to do it, but haven't had a luck because of my limited R skill. I will appreciate if someone helps this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Does it have any column names?.  If you are going to have columns with characters and numeric, the class will be character

Comment: Do you need the output to be written in a file?

Comment: Eventually, I want to use kable() to make a table... Then, should I create an ID or common variable to combine them? I did before, but I am looking for some other convenient way to combine it

Comment: May be the solution I posted helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formating the data with equal standard names:

```
#Format data
nxx <- rbind(colnames(xx),xx)
nyy <- rbind(colnames(yy),yy)
#Assign common names
nxx <- set_names(nxx,paste0('V',1:dim(nxx)[2]))
nyy <- set_names(nyy,paste0('V',1:dim(nyy)[2]))
#Bind
ndf <- rbind(nxx,nyy)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  V1    V2               V3               
  <chr> <chr>            <chr>            
1 vs    mean(mpg)        sd(mpg)          
2 0     16.6166666666667 3.86069941849919 
3 1     24.5571428571429 5.37897821090647 
4 am    mean(wt)         sd(wt)           
5 0     3.76889473684211 0.777400146838225
6 1     2.411            0.616981631277085
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` methods.  Convert the columns to `character` in each dataset, then add the first row (`add_row`) as the column name, and use `bind_rows` to bind the datasets

```
library(dplyr)  
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
xx %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.character(round(., 2)))) %>% 
   add_row(!!! setNames(names(.), names(.)), .before = 1) %>%
    rename_all(~ str_c('v', seq_along(.))) %>%
    bind_rows(yy %>% 
           mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.character(round(., 2)))) %>% 
   add_row(!!! setNames(names(.), names(.)), .before = 1) %>%
          rename_all(~ str_c('v', seq_along(.))))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  v1    v2        v3     
#  <chr> <chr>     <chr>  
#1 vs    mean(mpg) sd(mpg)
#2 0     16.62     3.86   
#3 1     24.56     5.38   
#4 am    mean(wt)  sd(wt) 
#5 0     3.77      0.78   
#6 1     2.41      0.62
```

---

Or this can be made slightly more compact

```
library(zeallot)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

list(xx, yy) %>% 
    map_dfr( ~ destructure(.x) %>%
               imap_dfr(~ c(.y, round(.x, 2))) %>%
               rename_with(~ str_c('v', seq_along(.))))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  v1    v2        v3     
#  <chr> <chr>     <chr>  
#1 vs    mean(mpg) sd(mpg)
#2 0     16.62     3.86   
#3 1     24.56     5.38   
#4 am    mean(wt)  sd(wt) 
#5 0     3.77      0.78   
#6 1     2.41      0.62
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list(xx, yy), function(x) 
             unname(rbind(colnames(x), round(x, 2)))))
```